# Connecting to MongoDB over SSL with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ssl

How do I connect to a MongoDB-server over SSL using Node.js?

I've read the sources of a few drivers ([mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs), [mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)) and I've been googling a while now, but can't seem to find any proper tutorials, guides or docs.

Comment: The 2nd result for `mongodb ssl node.js` might interest you https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/server.html

Comment: Hm.. I started fooling around with that, but didn't get it to work. I'll give it a new try.

Comment: And the moderator who voted to close: really? How is this not about programming? Let's just never write code that connects to databases then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb and nodejs SSl/Secure Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106940/mongodb-and-nodejs-ssl-secure-connection)

Comment: It sure is a duplicate when the other question was asked later... Stupid me for posting a new question when it was going to be asked 7 months later by someone else! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the `node-mongodb-native` has everything needed.

I got it up and running using the following:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var server = new mongo.Server('HOSTNAME', 27017, { ssl: true });
var db = new mongo.Db('NAME_OF_MY_DB', server, { w: 1 });
var auth = { user: 'USERNAME', pass: 'PASSWORD' };

db.open(function(err, db) {
  if (err) return console.log("error opening", err);

  db.authenticate(auth.user, auth.pass, function(err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log("error authenticating", err);

    console.log("authed?", result);

    db.collection('whatever').count(function(err, count) {
      if (err) return console.log("error counting", err);

      console.log("count", count);
      db.close()
    });
  });
});
```

**Edit**

You can also do ssl from [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/):

```
mongoose.createConnection(connString, { server: { ssl: true }})
```

Comment: why aren't sslCA,sslCert and sslKey not specified?

Answer (score 16):

#### Step 1: Obtain MongoDB 3.0

The first thing you need to know is that that SSL is only supported out-of-the-box by MongoDB 3.0 and later. Ubuntu does not have 3.0 in the default repositories, so here's how you get it:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.0.7 mongodb-org-server=3.0.7 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.7 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.7 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.7
```

3.0.7 is the latest stable version as of now, but feel free to substitute 3.0.7 with your favorite release.

#### Step 2: Obtain Private Key, Certificate, and PEM files

The PEM contains a Public Key Certificate and its associated Private Key. These files can either be obtained with IRL dollars from a Certificate Authroity or generated with OpenSSL like so:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out mongodb-cert.crt -keyout mongodb-cert.key
cat mongodb-cert.key mongodb-cert.crt > mongodb.pem
```

mongodb.pem will be used as the PEM file, mongodb-cert.key is the Private Key file, and mongodb-cert.crt is Certificate file which can also be used as the CA file. YOU WILL NEED ALL THREE OF THESE.

#### Step 3: Configure MongoD

We're going to assume that you copied these files to your /etc/ssl/ folder where they belong. Now we open up our MongoDB config file:

```
sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf
```

and modify the "# network interfaces" section like so:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  ssl:
    mode: allowSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
    #CAFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb-cert.crt
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: we are commenting out `bindIp`. THIS ALLOWS EXTERNAL CONNECTIONS to access your Mongo database. We assume that this is your end goal (*Why would your encrypt traffic on localhost?*), but you should only do this AFTER SETTING UP AUTHORIZATION RULES for your MongoDB server.

The CAFile is also commented out as it is optional. I will explain how to set up Certificate Authority trust at the end of this post.

As always, you must restart MongoDB before config file changes will take effect:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

DID YOUR SERVER FAIL TO START? You are on your own, but there is probably an issue with your certificate files. You can check start-up errors by running `mongod` manually:

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

#### Step 4: Test your server settings

Before we go messing with Node configurations, let's make sure that your server setup is working properly by connecting with the `mongo` command line client:

```
mongo --ssl --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --sslAllowInvalidCertificates
```

Unless the domain name on your certificate is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, the `--sslAllowInvalidHostnames` flag is necessary. Without it, you will probably get this error:

```
E NETWORK  The server certificate does not match the host name 127.0.0.1
E QUERY    Error: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for 
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

#### Step 5: Configure Node.JS / Mongoose

If you are using the `node-mongodb-native` package in your Node application, stop immediately and start using Mongoose. It's not that hard. That said, `mongoose.connect()` has virtually the same API as `mongodb.connect()`, so substitute appropriately.

```
    var fs = require('fs')
      , mongoose = require('mongoose')
      , mongoUri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?ssl=true"
      , mongoOpt = {
          "sslValidate": false,
          "sslKey": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
          "sslCert": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb-cert.crt')
        }
      ;

mongoose.connect(mongoUri, mongoOpt);
```

#### Step 6: [Optionally] verify your Certificates via a Certificate Authority

In order to validate your SSL Certificates, you need to obtain a CA (*or bundle*) file from your Certificate Authority. This will look a lot like your Certificate file, but will often contain multiple Certificates (*which forms a chain of trust to verify that a certificate is valid*). If you are using a self-signed certificate, you can use your `mongodb-cert.crt` as a CA file.

You will also need to ensure that your MongoDB server's hostname matches the one used to create the certificate.

#### Step 6.3: Update your `mongod` configuration

```
sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf
```

and modify the "# network interfaces" section like so:

```
# network interfaces net:   port: 27017   #bindIp: 127.0.0.1   ssl:
    mode: allowSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb-ca.crt

sudo service mongod restart
```

#### Step 6.4: Test your server settings

```
mongo --ssl --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/mongodb-ca.crt --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```

Mongo Clients can pass in the CA file as well to verify that they are talking to the correct server. This is done with the `--sslCAFile` parameter

Mongo Servers configured with a CAFile require that clients possess a valid Certificate **AND** the Private Key for the server. In the mongo shell client, this is done by passing in the `--sslPEMKeyFile` parameter.

Without a PEM file (*which contains the server's Certificate*), you may see this error:

```
I NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed
E QUERY    Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:27017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 }
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

The server can be configured to accept requests from clients without a PEM file by enabling `net.ssl.weakCertificateValidation`, but you will be weakening your security for no real gain.

#### Step 6.5: Configure Node.JS / Mongoose

There are a couple of gotchas here, so bear with me.

First, you NEED to have `node-mongodb-native` `2.0` or later. If you are using Mongoose, then you NEED Mongoose `4.0` or later. Previous Mongoose versions use `node-mongodb-native` `1.*` which does not support Certificate validation in any capacity whatsoever.

Secondly, there is no `sslAllowInvalidHostnames` or similar option available in node-mongodb-native. This is not something that `node-mongodb-native` developers can fix (*I would have by now*) because the native TLS library available in Node 0.10.* offers no option for this. In Node 4.* and 5.*, there is a `checkServerIdentity` option which offers hope, but switching from the original Node branch to the branch after the io.js merge can cause a bit of headache at the current time.

So let's try this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , mongoUri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?ssl=true"
  , mongoOpt = {
      "server": { 
        "sslKey": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
        "sslCert": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb-cert.crt'),
        "sslCa": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb-ca.crt')
      }
    }
  ;
```

If you are getting hostname/IP mismatch errors, either fix your certificate, or negate all this hard work by disabling `sslValidate`:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , mongoUri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?ssl=true"
  , mongoOpt = {
      "server": {
        "sslValidate": false,
        "sslKey": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
        "sslCert": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb-cert.crt'),
        "sslCa": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb-ca.crt')
      }
    }
  ;
```

> [Source](http://www.bainweb.com/2015/11/connecting-to-mongodb-over-tlsssl-with.html)

Comment: See my comment on your [duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33926129/1677912). Same applies here.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks so much for the very detailed steps!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to authenticate using a certificate, using `node-mongodb-native`:

```
var buffer = require('fs').readFileSync("mongodb.pem");
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://hostname:27017/test?ssl=true", {
    sslKey: buffer,
    sslCert: buffer,
    sslValidate: false //in case of self-generated certificate
}, function(err, db) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(db);
    db.close();
});
```