# Setting up MongoDB in a docker container with Certbot's certificates

Tags: linux, mongodb, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

How to I configure my MongoDB's ssl certificates?

I want to host my MongoDB myself. I currently have a Linode container running, on it I've installed `certbot` and had it acquire certificates for the domain I want to use for my database.

I'm using this `docker-compose.yml` file to deploy the MongoDB container:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
       - ./db-data:/data/db
       - ./mongo-config:/data/config
       - ./certs:/data/certs
    ports:
       - "0.0.0.0:27017:27017"
    restart: always
    environment:
       - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=exampleuser
       - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=examplepassword
   command: --config=/data/config/mongo.conf
```

> and before someone mentions using nginx streams, certbot doesn't support them [(see issue)](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5565)

An my mongo config found at `./mongo-config/mongo.conf`:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: # This is where I need help, it would be in /data/certs from the container's perspective
```

Every guide mentions copying Certbot's files into a docker volume, so I setup ./certs to mount into `/data/certs` and copied them their. I've tried ever combination of every permutation of the files Certbot creates in the `PEMKeyFile` and the `CAFile` fields and nothing works. I'd get this error every time I tried:

```
error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

Guides I've already tried:

- [How to: Configure SSL For MongoDB](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/175272-configure-ssl-for-mongodb)
- [Configure mongod and mongos for TLS/SSL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)
- [Certbot User Guide](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#managing-certificates)
- [Setup Mongo 3.6 TSL/SSL with Letsencrypt](https://gist.github.com/j0e1in/7621b23bc3ef8f942f66e2d8ac2aa2cf) | this one mentioned that I have to download a certificate that expires TODAY (sept 30, 2021)
- [Securing MongoDB with TLS, Authentication and LetsEncrypt](https://sebworks.com/securing-mongodb-tls-auth-letsencrypt/)

Related: [LetsEncrypt SSL Certificate Validation Failed with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822387/letsencrypt-ssl-certificate-validation-failed-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
docker run -it --name data.domain.com --network docker_network -v /path/to/ssl/certs:/ssl:ro -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass mongo --tlsMode requireTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile /ssl/fullchain-key.pem --tlsCAFile /etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem
```

Important things:

- name of docker container has to match certificate
- do 'cat fullchain.pem privkey.pem > fullchain-key.pem'

You have to adapt this to docker-compose. Try this out and if you need more help, let me know