# Meteor.js connection to Mongo using X509 certificate auth

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ssl, meteor, x509

I am trying to set up passwordless authentication between Meteor.js apps and Mongo server.

To do that, I need to present pem and crt files to the connection. MONGO_URL connection string takes only [parameters](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/connection-string/) about how to perform auth, but no references to files with certs. I assume, I need to pass in the cert file to connection as a parameter. Similar as described in [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connecting/).

How to do it in Meteor.js?

Basically I want to achieve equivalent of doing:

```
mongo mongo.example.com/example -ssl -sslPEMKeyFile client.pem --sslCAFile server.crt
```

and then as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/)

```
db.getSiblingDB("$external").auth(
  {
    mechanism: "MONGODB-X509",
    user: "CN=myName,OU=myOrgUnit,O=myOrg,L=myLocality,ST=myState,C=myCountry"
  }
)
```

this works fine when using mogo client, but within Meteor I have so far only gotten to the point of understanding that I would most likely need to use connection string below (or something similar)

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo.example.com:27017/example?ssl=true&authSource=$external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509
```

but question remains - how to pass certificates to the connection?

Update: there is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381561/connecting-to-mongodb-over-ssl-with-node-js/24428587#24428587) that deals with the issue using native noddejs mongo driver. question is - how to port this to Meteor.

Update 2015-12-31: I have accepted the answer that points to using different connection object when defining the Collection. It is a hassle to do it for each collection separately, but it seems to be the only way this is doable right now. Also, if need arises, probably some MySslCollection can be created, that others can use to inherit connection details. This has not been tested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated Answer (Jan 2024)

This answer has not aged well. Meteor and Mongo have changed a decent amount over the years. [Please check the latest docs entries on X.509 cert auth.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/authentication/#x.509)

But as of now there is a [MongoClientSettings](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/connection/connection-options/#using-mongoclientsettings) object that can be used to specify things.

### Updated Answer (version 1.4 & up)

As pointed out by another answer, the options here have changed as of version 1.4 and you can now call

`Mongo.setConnectionOptions({ ... });`

please see [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/authentication/#x.509) for more details.

### Old Answer (pre version 1.4)

This was a fun rabbit hole... I think I have found one solution/workaround to your problem (there may be others).

The quick description of my workaround is to specify the mongodb server options when creating your collections. This must be done on the server code only to avoid handing out your ssl key/cert. Like so:

```
new Mongo.Collection("collection_name", {
    connection: DDP.connect("mongodb://mongo.example.com:27017/example?ssl=true&authSource=$external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509", {
        server: {
            sslCert:[CERT_CONTENTS],
            sslKey:[KEY_CONTENTS],
            sslValidate:false
        }
    })
});
```

**Hacky methods**

Since you asked if there is a way to do this without adding the options to every collection created I decided to take another look. I have not tested these methods, but they seem sound, if very hacky.

**1)** Set up a function to run on the connection status using undocumented options argument passthru in the reconnect method. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L996

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  var status = Meteor.status();
  if(status == 'failed')
    Meteor.reconnect({
      server: {
        sslCert:[CERT_CONTENTS],
        sslKey:[KEY_CONTENTS],
        sslValidate:false
      }
    });
});
```

**2)** Monkey patch the default connection code (this I am less sure of working since I haven't taken the time to understand when the mongo internal code for this actually gets set in the first place). https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js

```
MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver = _.once(function () {
  var connectionOptions = {
    server: {
      sslCert:[CERT_CONTENTS],
      sslKey:[KEY_CONTENTS],
      sslValidate:false
    }
  };

  var mongoUrl = process.env.MONGO_URL;

  if (process.env.MONGO_OPLOG_URL) {
    connectionOptions.oplogUrl = process.env.MONGO_OPLOG_URL;
  }

  if (! mongoUrl)
    throw new Error("MONGO_URL must be set in environment");

  return new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(mongoUrl, connectionOptions);
});
```

**The journey to these answers:**

Starting from the answer you linked, I found where Meteor creates its MongoDB connection: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js#L173

Then I found where that was getting called: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/3d2282d9ad0b570b913a70d215cd968019d912df/packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js#L4

Tracking down where that got called led me to the fact that Collections instantiate the connection: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/15cdbca24888bfdff3ad43c1891a1719c09b3dc5/packages/mongo/collection.js#L102

I could see from there that some options can override the use of the default Mongo connnection that has no options specified. Looking in the Meteor docs for collections http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection shows:

> Options
>
> connection Object
>
> The server connection that will manage this collection. Uses the default connection if not specified. Pass the return value of calling DDP.connect to specify a different server. Pass null to specify no connection. Unmanaged (name is null) collections cannot specify a connection.

So looking at the docs for DDP.connect http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddp_connect we reach a dead end since it only takes a url... but wait... after searching through the code on github I can see that DDP.connect does take an options param: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L1641

Thus concludes our quest.

Comment: yeah, I also found Collection options as a possibility, but discarded it quickly as it felt that does not help too much if I just want to replace existing server auth setup with the new one without changing all the code. But it is certainly the possibility. Maybe I had discarded it too early. Maybe it is possible to overload Collection object, and then have all my collections use new MySslCollection instead? Hmm.

Comment: Yeah pretty much any step in the code I linked to could be changed. I also thought this solution is a little 'dirty' but it seems like the only 'official' way to do it at the moment. I was considering making this a patch to meteor, and at the very least I will try to get their docs for DDP.connect fixed.

Comment: is it possible to somehow add a file to meteor project, that would contain modified/default Collection, with those options defined, that would be then be picked up and used by/inherited all other collections? That way we could avoid having to modify projects code just to change db auth mechanism

Comment: If you get your ssl set up correctly on the mongo server then all you need is the env variable MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo.example.com:27017/example?ssl=true

Comment: if you have an answer on how to set up client and server certs, so they would be exchanged when connection is established, without changing anything except connection string - then please write answer and I will gladly accept it. right now I do not see such possibility - &ssl=true only encrypts connection, it is not doing anything with authentication and authorization without providing certs. and how to do that - that is my question

Comment: You are right, I was distracted by many posts about ssl=true being all that should be needed. My current post is still the only way to use certs for auth & auth.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the previous answers are correct ([craigts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500312/1177832), [user1887896](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43016099/1177832)), however I'd like to add:

1. I've put a very simple package up on Atmosphere ([danwild:set-connection-options](https://atmospherejs.com/danwild/set-connection-options)) to simplify this process (or at the very least provide a concrete example of *how* and *where* `Mongo.setConnectionOptions` might actually be used, as there is little documentation available).
2. Just reiterating that if you use any packages which access Mongo in your project (e.g. `accounts-base`), you must ensure your call to `Mongo.setConnectionOptions` happens before they are loaded.

   - How to do this? Good question.
   - As far as I can see there is no official way to ensure your package loads before another (the other way around is of course well supported).
   - The simplest way I've seen to do this is, is by editing the package order in `.meteor/packages`, i.e. placing `danwild:set-connection-options` at the top of the file.

Comment: I am not actively using Meteor anymore, so I can not verify. But it is nice that there are nee package!

Answer (score 2):

Since Meteor 1.4, Mongo connection options can be configured by calling:

```
Mongo.setConnectionOptions({ ... });
```

The function must be called early during initialization.  One way is to create a local Meteor package that is loaded before other packages.  See https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-with-the-new-mongodb-3-2-1-compose-io/17763/10 and Meteor GitHub issue #7455 for details.

Meteor 1.4 release notes: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v14-2016-07-25