# How to connect to MongoDB server with SSL in NodeJS 0.10.x?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB with ssl option using old NodejS version. Connection fails with a timeout error.

I found that connection start works after iojs 3.0.0 release. But I must use NodeJS 0.10.40 in my environment.

It seems a **data event is never emitted on a tls socket**.

My original problem is there: https://github.com/thaliproject/jxcore/issues/115

Code example and output:

```
const mongodb     = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://****?ssl=true'; // Any cloud server with ssl

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    console.log('Connected correctly to server');

    db.close();
});
```

> { [MongoError: connection 0 to
>   aws-us-east-1-portal.28.dblayer.com:23087 timed out]   name:
>   'MongoError',   message: 'connection 0 to
>   aws-us-east-1-portal.28.dblayer.com:23087 timed out' }

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33926082/7635845 Excellent answer definitly you will find a solution

Comment: It's not a problem with SSL certificate. For example, I want to connect to MongoDB Atlas but can't, due to a timeout.

Comment: Is this running on an embedded device, what's the reason behind staying on 0.10.40? Your efforts are clearly better focused in the Node upgrade direction. I promise you there's very high chance you'll hit another bug even if you fix the TLS thing. 0.10.x is archaic by Node standards.

Comment: Yes... I use jxcore, and it can't be upgraded to new NodeJS, unfortunately.